# VBScript runtime error: Object required error started appearing randomly - code worked fine until today

Tags: shell, batch-file, vbscript, scripting

I'm currently running a simple batch file (.bat) that kicks off a plethora of vbs scripts. The file has been running perfectly ever day for the past two weeks, until today.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
Echo ONLY CONTINUE IF YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU WANT TO RUN ALL OF THESE TASKS!!!!!!
timeout /t 30

START cscript "FILEPATHHERE\vbsscriptname.vbs"
Echo vbs script is running!
timeout /t 30


ECHO Complete!
PAUSE >nul
```

There are about 100 of those vbs scripts. Like I said, they all ran fine until today. The error I am getting is:

> FILEPATH\VBS SCRIPTNAME.vbs(7, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required

I did a little research on this error, and I'm not really sure how it applies to what I'm trying to do, especially since this was working fine for weeks. Nothing has changed in the code, so I'm not sure where to start trouble shooting.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from Line 7 of `VBS SCRIPTNAME.vbs`. You would need to include that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, within minutes of posting this on stackoverflow, because I couldn't find an answer..well.. I found an answer here: http://support.sas.com/kb/35/654.html

This doesn't explain why the file has been running fine for weeks, but I fixed it with this method and it is working now, *for now...*

Being that this version of windows was 64-bit, it needs to be directed toward the 32-bit version of cscript. (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript) I replaced cscript with the 32bit version and all is well now.

```
Echo ONLY CONTINUE IF YOU ARE SURE THAT YOU WANT TO RUN ALL OF THESE TASKS!!!!!!
timeout /t 30

START C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cscript "FILEPATHHERE\vbsscriptname.vbs"
Echo vbs script is running!
timeout /t 30


ECHO Complete!
PAUSE >nul
```

Comment: FYI the path `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64` is where _32-bit_ applications and assemblies are stored. I _think_ your architecture references are backwards

Comment: @Matt I was just adding that to the code snippet to show an example. And yes, you are correct. I flipped my 32 and 64 references around. Thank you! (I'll fix it in an edit)